# Is my circuit ok, using an N channel MOSFET to switch a P channel MOSFET for a high side switch

Tags: mosfet, switches, p-channel

I'm using an CP361 voltage protection to ensure 5 V, this switches an N channel MOSFET which then creates a link to ground for the P channel MOSFET.

The link to ground turns on the P channel MOSFET and allows power to the circuit.
Do I have everything in order here from my schematic? Thanks

Comment: What’s the purpose?

Comment: To allow around 5v 1amp of current through. This would be too much alone for the NCP361, so using it to ensure only 5v, but using pchannel mosfet to switch the circuit.

Comment: What prevents you from tying +5VP to +5V?

Comment: it is for overvoltage protection so need to go through the NCP361 regulator.

Comment: Your NCP361 will just give +5V as soon as +5VP goes to 5 V and your MOSFET will bridge together +5VP and +5V anyway? EDIT: it’s not a 5 V regulator but a voltage supervisor.

Comment: The circuit seems to be working ok on my breadboard, if I'm over 5V, the circuit and my load at the end of +5V on the right of the diagram is correctly broken.

Comment: Have you tested the transient response? If +5VP goes to 10V quickly, will Q2 open quickly enough?

Comment: Have you made sure that the gate of Q2 moves from 5V to 0V slow enough to make sure that inrush current does not kill Q2? If you have a very high cap on +5V which makes it rise very slowly, you could theoretically have a problem. Better to rule it out through simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NCP361 voltage regulator

NCP361 is an overvoltage-protecting switch. You're using it to control a CMOS Sziklai pair. Fine enough - this configuration is fast to turn off, and slower to turn on - just about what you want.

You seem to be using same size complemetary devices as Q1-Q2. That's not necessary. The first device can be much smaller than the 2nd one - it will react faster as well. A logic-level 500mA-1A 10V mosfet will be plenty enough, just to keep the gate capacitance small.

C5*R1 determine the protection time constant. In your case, it's 1E-6*1E3=1ms. It will take a couple ms to turn the output off. Is that fast enough? If too slow, C5 can be made smaller.

Side note: Don't use those "bridge" crossings for wires on a schematic. It's an outdated practice and unnecessary to communicate your intent. If anything, modify the NCP361 component symbol to have GND on the bottom, making the current flow on the schematic more conventional (top-to-bottom, left-to-right).

E.g.:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD1DiA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

P.S. To get the no connect "X" symbol in KiCad schematic editor, press the Q key :)